# How to install wood board & batten shutters on wood siding?

Tags: installation, shutters

Do I leave a gap between shutter and window trim? I know I predrill the holes, but not sure if it should be in the batten or each vertical board.

Comment: Welcome to DIYSE. Please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first question is a matter of aesthetics and is up to you. However, I tend to like to leave air gaps so moisture doesn't linger after rain. I'd even be inclined to use short standoff tubes to keep the shutters off the siding.

The second partly depends on the construction of the shutters, but two screws in each of the calling battens should do. If they're very heavy shutters or of questionable build integrity you should explain that in your post.

Comment: Simple 1X6 (3) shutters, 40" in length with slight gaps between the boards to allow for expansion.  I've just seen where some people attached via screws through the batten to the house and others just threw the vertical boards to the house.  Wasn't sure which was best.  I don't want the attachment screws necessarily to show, but my shutters are stained and I think they'll blend in or I'll add some stain to the screw heads or on top of putty if I countersink slightly.  They are relatively light in weight.